# How is the fit function in SimpleImputer working to find the mean in the Salary column as well when just the Age column is given as its argument?

Tags: data-cleaning, preprocessing

The only argument inside the fit function of SimpleImputer is: 'Age'. Yet the returned output worked on the 'Salary' column as well. That is what I am unable to understand.

Here is my code (considering all the necessary libraries imported):

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan)
imputer = imputer.fit(df[['Age']])    
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.fit_transform(X[:, 1:3])
print(X)
```

Dataset:

```
   Country   Age   Salary Purchased
0   France  44.0  72000.0        No
1    Spain  27.0  48000.0       Yes
2  Germany  30.0  54000.0        No
3    Spain  38.0  61000.0        No
4  Germany  40.0      NaN       Yes
5   France  35.0  58000.0       Yes
6    Spain   NaN  52000.0        No
7   France  48.0  79000.0       Yes
8  Germany  50.0  83000.0        No
9   France  37.0  67000.0       Yes
```

Output:

```
[['France' 44.0 72000.0]
 ['Spain' 27.0 48000.0]
 ['Germany' 30.0 54000.0]
 ['Spain' 38.0 61000.0]
 ['Germany' 40.0 63777.77777777778]
 ['France' 35.0 58000.0]
 ['Spain' 38.77777777777778 52000.0]
 ['France' 48.0 79000.0]
 ['Germany' 50.0 83000.0]
 ['France' 37.0 67000.0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
imputer = imputer.fit(df[['Age']])    
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.fit_transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

You are again applying *"fit"* with **fit_trasnform**. Try with *"transform"* only

*You will get a value error*

> *ValueError: X has 3 features per sample, expected 2*

Comment: So it is because of the ```X[:, 1:3]``` that the missing value for Salary was found and applied?

Comment: Your first fit is over written by the fit in the fit_transform.

Comment: Please mark the question as "Accepted" if you found so

Comment: Okay. I have one last thing to ask. 
```imputer = imputer.fit(df[['Salary']])```
I put in the above line as well, so it makes sense to me, though it hardly makes any difference. 
But I don't know what the correct way of getting the final result is. What could have been done differently?

Comment: Keep the columns same, with every function be it fit, transform, or fit transform. X[ :, 1:3]  line is doing what you are trying. Line above it is not needed